# Gradient-like systems and limit sets

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Suppose we have an autonomous ode $$\dot{x} = f(x)$$ which corresponds to a $\underline{gradient-like}$ dynamical system, $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that the set of initial conditions that have in their limit set an unstable fixed point (i.e fixed point whose Jacobian has an eigenvalue with positive real part) is measure zero? Thanks

Comment: What is meant by a gradient-like dynamical system? That $f = \nabla U$ for some potential function $U$?

Comment: It means that there exists a function $V$ such that $\dot V = \nabla V \cdot \dot x \leq 0$ with equality holding at fixed points. So one can prove that for each point $x_{0}$, the limit set of $x_{0}$ consists only of fixed points.